# Actionscript 3 open in new window

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am new at Actionscript and when I say new, I mean yesterday...

I have this code here that opens a new link

```
myButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,goThere);
function goThere(e:MouseEvent){
    var request = new URLRequest("http://www.jamessuske.com/freelance/korkis/3DLibrary.php");
    navigateToURL(request);
}
```

How do I get this to open in a new window with sizes?

Thanks,
J

Comment: To specify a window size, you would need to call a javascript function (using ExternalInterface) which itself would open and size a new window.

Answer (score 12):

I would think adding `_blank` to `navigateToURL` will open a new window (see [docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/package.html#navigateToURL%28%29)):

```
function goThere(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    var request = new URLRequest("http://www.jamessuske.com/freelance/korkis/3DLibrary.php");
    navigateToURL(request, "_blank");
}
myButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goThere);
```

And about *sizing* the window ... I think that's *not possible* (but hey, someone can prove me wrong ;) )

### EDIT

OK, maybe you can also size it by using [ExternalInterface](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0_de/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html) (look at example at the end) (untested):

Edit your embed html:
Add

```
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
```

to your **embed html** and add the following call at the start of you **AS3** code:

```
flash.system.Security.allowDomain("*")
```

Then the following code should work:

```
function goThere(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    ExternalInterface.call("open", "http://www.jamessuske.com/freelance/korkis/3DLibrary.php", "_blank", "width=300,height=400,left=100,top=200");
}
```

Comment: That is a great little code snippet. I never thought about using ExternalInterface to make it happen.

Comment: @user1269625: Just verified again - it works. Just read the official documentation about ExternalInterface (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html) and embed the swf as described.

Comment: Additional info: In Chrome you have to watch out for the security restrictions (opening local html-file obviously denies using ExternalInterface - hosting it (localhost or any other webserver) makes it work ;) )

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe you can control the new window size, but you can open it in a new window using the `target` property.

```
navigateToURL( request, "_blank" );
```

See [`navigateToURL()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/package.html#navigateToURL%28%29) on the LiveDocs.

You should also note that in AS3, you **must always** include a datatype with every single object you create.

```
function goThere(e:MouseEvent):void {
    var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.jamessuske.com/freelance/korkis/3DLibrary.php");
    navigateToURL(request);
}
```

Note the ":DATATYPE" after the variable declaration and also after the function declaration. I do not believe Flash Pro will point this out to you, but every single object you create has to be datatyped. AS3 (along with Java and most C-based languages) uses strict datatyping whereas Javascript, PHP, and AS2 use loose datatyping where an object takes the datatype of its value.

Comment: +1 though I'd add that it isn't strictly necessary to add a datatype after a variable if you're not in strict mode - but it's ALWAYS a good idea, especially if you're new to the concept, to do it. Not only does it result in optimal code, but it makes debugging MILES easier, and allows others to make sense of your code more easily.

Comment: @MickMalone1983 Good points. It's worth noting that if you ever move to FlashBuilder, you'll get warnings if you don't (in 4.5/4.5, I believe it wouldn't compile if you missed one)

Comment: My Flashbuilder won't warn me now, not sure what I've done, it just rebuilds the last working version, which can be a real pain if you don't notice! I think AS3 is a good gateway language for a JS/similar dev moving into stricter languages like Java/C++, it's quite forgiving, has the cool JS stuff (1st class functions, objects-as-lists) mixed with 'real' language/OO features (properties, interfaces, typing, inheritance etc)

Answer (score 1):

The code by Warappa works, but may lack some additional info required by a starting AS developer. Hopefully the comments and full code will make it work for you.

```
// This makes the ExternalInterface class available
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;

myButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goThere);
function goThere(e:MouseEvent)
{
    // Store the URL as a variable for readability
    var url : String = "http://www.jamessuske.com/freelance/korkis/3DLibrary.php";

    // Check if we have access to the External interface (are we running in a browser?)
    if (ExternalInterface.available) {
        ExternalInterface.call('window.open', url, '', 'width=400,height=300' );
    }
}
```

Also, I should mention that this might only work if you run it off a webserver. This can be localhost or a remote webserver. This has to do with the Flash Security model. For options on the width, height and many more, take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.open